# Microblink : Scanning both side of ID card

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, microblink, blinkid

I am trying to scan both side of national card with mircoblink, based on their documentation for scanning both side you have to use `MBDocumentVerificationOverlayViewController` for controller and `MBBlinkIdCombinedRecognizer` for recognizer. but only my front side scanning works well.
I am using demo serial key, I don't know is it related to to my serial key or not.

here is my code:

```
    /** Create BlinkID recognizer */
    blinkIdRecognizer = MBBlinkIdCombinedRecognizer()

    /** Create BlinkID settings */
    let settings : MBDocumentVerificationOverlaySettings = MBDocumentVerificationOverlaySettings()

    /** Crate recognizer collection */
    let recognizerCollection : MBRecognizerCollection = MBRecognizerCollection(recognizers: [blinkIdRecognizer!])

    /** Create your overlay view controller */
    let documentOverlayViewController : MBDocumentVerificationOverlayViewController = MBDocumentVerificationOverlayViewController(settings: settings, recognizerCollection: recognizerCollection, delegate: self)

    /** Create recognizer view controller with wanted overlay view controller */
    let recognizerRunneViewController : UIViewController = MBViewControllerFactory.recognizerRunnerViewController(withOverlayViewController: documentOverlayViewController)

    /** Present the recognizer runner view controller. You can use other presentation methods as well (instead of presentViewController) */
    present(recognizerRunneViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is my delegate code:

```
extension MyVC: MBDocumentVerificationOverlayViewControllerDelegate {

    func documentVerificationOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanningFirstSide(_ documentVerificationOverlayViewController: MBDocumentVerificationOverlayViewController) {
        print("First Side Scanned")
    }

    func documentVerificationOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanning(_ documentVerificationOverlayViewController: MBDocumentVerificationOverlayViewController, state: MBRecognizerResultState) {

        if (self.blinkIdRecognizer?.combinedResult.resultState == MBRecognizerResultState.valid) {
            guard let result = blinkIdRecognizer?.combinedResult else {
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if self.blinkIdRecognizer?.combinedResult.scanningFirstSideDone == true {

                } else {
                    documentVerificationOverlayViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    func documentVerificationOverlayViewControllerDidTapClose(_ documentVerificationOverlayViewController: MBDocumentVerificationOverlayViewController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

And scanning first side delegate never get called, but I see response in `DidFinish`

thanks for any help

Comment: please share more details

Comment: This is the same code that provided by their company, but It doesn't work and they told to tag us in stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of the SDK are you using?

In version 5.2, we have added scanning for both the front and backside of the German ID.

You can download the latest release here:
https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios/releases

Can you please test it now and let us know if that worked?

Milan

Comment: Hi, my pod version was 5.1.1, when I update it to 5.2.0 , it works well

Comment: Do you have any plan to support Iranian national card??

Comment: We have it on our roadmap to support it in the future, but currently, we can't give you an exact date when it will be supported.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I've worked with microblink was over a year ago but if I recall correctly `documentVerificationOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanningFirstSide` is only available for the supported id cards.

If you're scanning an ID card from another country you'll need to implement that yourself.

For example:

```
func documentVerificationOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanning(_ documentVerificationOverlayViewController: MBDocumentVerificationOverlayViewController, state: MBRecognizerResultState) {
    if step == .first {
        // Present another ViewController for the back
        showBackScanner()
    } else {
        processData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but `documentVerificationOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanning` never get called, do I have to set another delegate, in showBackScanner do you call any method or something I didn't find anything related to showing back side scanner. I am looking to scan Germany ID card

Comment: What do you mean by you see a response in `DidFinish` ?

Comment: `documentVerificationOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanningFirstSide` this is never get called but after scanning first side `documentVerificationOverlayViewControllerDidFinishScanning` get called and I will get front side response, I looked at their interfaces and didn't find anything to switch between back side

Comment: For unsupported IDs, I just presented a new DocumentOverlayViewController and handled the state myself

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with android. Is there any callback method whether the front page scanning done and rear page scanning done in the multi page scanning? @ahbou